# The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli. What is wrong in my procedure?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I run ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server to build, this error happens

```
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D
module.js:559
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:557:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:484:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Downloads/react_app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
```

therefore I run npm install webpack-cli -D command and I run the command again but zsh: no such file or directory: ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server error happens.I followed procedure to build react.js so I think my building procedure has no error.So what should I do to fix this?Does this error cause difference of libraries version?How should I fix this?
My webpack.config.js is

```
var publidDir = __dirname + '/public';
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: publidDir,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: publidDir
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem after update some dependencies. Check the webpack-dev-server version, I had 3.1.3 and I was getting same error as you. This what I have right now:

```
"webpack": "^3.10.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.9.7"
```

Answer (score 0):

include below versions on your package.json file:

`"dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.7"
  },`

Answer (score -1):

You're missing webpack-dev-server you need to install it with

```
npm install webpack-dev-server -D
```

or if using yarn

```
yarn add webpack-dev-server -D
```

Comment: I installed npm install webpack-dev-server -D,but what command should i run to build it?After installing webpack-dev-server -D,I run ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server but Error: Cannot find module 'webpack' error happens.

Comment: @user9170657 You need to also install webpack you can do that with npm install webpack -D

Comment: I also installed webpack and I run command ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server but ✖ ｢wds｣: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:

Comment: object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

Comment: error happens.And also I run command  webpack, but totally same error happens.What is wrong ?What command should I run to build?

Comment: Can you post your webpack configuration?

Comment: I added webpack.config.js in my question.If u know something, please help me.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error did you get the solution.